# Which firmware should I download for iPad 2 A1397?

Tags: ipad, firmware

I want to update an iPad 2, I've done this before but not with this model yet

The model is A1397, according to Apple warranty check is: **iPad 2 3G (Verizon)**

I want to download the file .ipsw directly from Apple server without using iTunes

Which version I download: **iPad 2 (CDMA)** or **iPad 2 (GSM)**?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find out is actually to use iTunes & see which file it downloads.
You don't need to let it go through the entire process, you can set it to download only.

Based on personal experience - my iPhone, according to all online evidence, [& the fact that it has a SIM card] is a UK GSM model - yet iTunes always downloads the CDMA update for it.
I've never attempted to download the GSM instead to see what happens.

I always do an update in clear steps…

- Download only
- Sync
- Backup
- Update

[Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-2-wi-fi-cdma-verizon-a-gps-specs.html) lists that as as CDMA, btw.

For independent download - http://ipswdownloader.com carries listings of Apple's file locations, but they don't list 8.2 yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need the CDMA version. ([Direct link](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios8.2/031-06559-20150309-D4DC9D32-C1FE-11E4-8981-3F803780E501/iPad2,3_8.2_12D508_Restore.ipsw))

Edit: oops, didn't see your question has already been answered.